# Where are the log files for the service command?

Tags: services, aws

We are trying to migrate our Linux system to AWS.

The existing environment uses the `service` command to start and stop a Java application:

```
service oursystem start
service oursystem status 
service oursystem stop
```

On the new AWS box, the `service` command appears from the command terminal to complete without an error, but the application is not started, and the application logs show nothing.

Where are the log files which the `service` command produces stored?

Thanks

Comment: Most likely, the AWS system uses `systemd` (if you revealed the distro and its version, this could be confirmed). If so, the `service` command is an alias for `systemctl`, and logs are in the journal, which you can read using the `journalctl` command. For a quick status of your app, `systemctl status oursystem` might work. Eventually, you should create a `systemd` *unit* for your application.